# file css not apply in IE 8 in win xp, 9 in win 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with CSS file. The CSS file is not work with IE8 in Win XP and IE 9 in Win 7 but work fine in Win 8, IE 10 in Win 7 and firefox and chrome. Please let me know how to make it work in all versions. when i view source, CSS file is there but it isn't applied to the page
Thanks everyone for read.

Comment: You can show your CSS code? Some times we must do some tricks in the css code to work in the IE ancient versions

Answer (score -1):

Some times we must do some tricks in the css code to work in the IE ancient versions and other browsers.

For example, to apply opacity on a element, I normally do:

```
.withOpacity {

  /* IE 8 */ -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  /* IE 5-7 */
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -o-filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);

  /* Netscape */ -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  /* Safari 1.x */ -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  /* Good browsers */
    -ms-opacity: 0.6;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

So, the `opacity` property is universal but sometimes to be supported to some browsers we must join the respective prefix before. Look [this page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/css-vendor-prefixes.htm) to understand better, for example.

Sometimes, to force an IE ancient version to apply a css property we must join a `*` before the property and just this is enough, like this:

```
.smallElement
{
    width: 20px;
    *width: 20px
}
```

And for example, to create a required field indicator I normally do this:

```
.fieldRequired:after,
.requiredIndicator
{
    content: "*";
    color: red;
    vertical-align: top
} 

.fieldRequired 
{
    zoom: expression(this.doneReq ? '1' : (
      function(el) {el.innerHTML += '<span title="This is a required field!" class="requiredIndicator">*</span>'; return el.doneReq=true;})(this));
}
```

In other words, the IE ancient versions can't apply the css code on the `.fieldRequired:after`, so with the expression/function created in the `.fieldRequired` class we bind the same behavior with html code.

Comment: my code is ok, just css file is not work,
i put it in the end of head tag but it not apply, in >IE10 it work ok, i don't know how

Comment: You can show your header code? CSS file not working couldn't be true. Or the CSS file is not loading or the CSS properties aren't be reading and for that my answer must solve the problem. If the CSS file is not loading, can be a reference problem or can be missing some tag ending.

Comment: You already tried to debug on IE 7 (for example) if CSS file exists on HTML header and if it properties are implemented hover the respective HTML elements?